# Effective Torelli theorem for K3 surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

The proof of the Torelli theorem I've seen goes something like:

Put $M$ the moduli space of marked $K3$ surfaces, and $D$ the period domain s.t there is a natural map $$P: M \to D$$.

Up to lies, here is the proof;
One shows that $M$ has 2 components, and then the following two hard statements:

1. $P$ is locally etale
2. $P$ is surjective

Together we obtain that $P$ is a covering map, and since $D$ is simply connected by computation each component is an isomorphism.

Lies: ($M$ is not well behaved, not hausdorff and stuff, but let's ignore that).

This has the feel of a constructive proof but I don't see it.
Given a $K3$ that is $X$ and $g: H^2(X) \to H^2(X)$ a hodge isomorphism preserving ample class, how do we build the geometric isomorphism?

I think we should be building using the proof some family of $K3$ surfaces which transports the cohomology like $g$, and then build a analytic flow that would give the actual isomorphism. Can someone make sense of this?